# Header in UICollectionView causes it to disappear if rendered to PDF

Tags: swift, pdf, uikit

I have a collectionView that I generate off screen before rendering it to a PDF. It works fine until I add section headers, at which point cells and headers all disappear.

I've found that if I add the view on screen somewhere before rendering the PDF, it shows the header and cells as normal. Can I avoid this?

Here's my class:

```
public class PDFView: UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet public var contentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var columns: Int = 4
var rows: Int = 4
var headerHeight: CGFloat = 35


public override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.customInit()
}

public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.customInit()
}

public func customInit() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PDFView", owner: self, options: nil)
    
    self.addSubview(self.contentView)
    self.contentView.frame = self.bounds
    self.contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    
    contentView.backgroundColor = .white
    
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "GalleryViewHeaderCell", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier:"GalleryViewHeaderCell")
    
    collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "PDFViewRowCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    
    
}



public func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    project.scenesSorted.count
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    project.scenesSorted[section].assetURLs.count
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PDFViewRowCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.random
    return cell
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    let availableHeight = collectionView.bounds.height - (headerHeight*CGFloat(project.scenesSorted.count))
    
    let cellWidth: CGFloat = (collectionView.bounds.width / columns)
    let cellHeight: CGFloat = (availableHeight / rows)
    
    return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
}


public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "GalleryViewHeaderCell", for: indexPath) as! GalleryViewHeaderCell

    return headerView
   }


public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: headerHeight)
}

}
```

If I remove the `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` function, it works again. If I set the size to 0 in `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection`, it works again. But with everything there as it should be, no cells or headers appear.

Here's the PDF rendering code as well:

```
        let frameView = UIView()
        frameView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 612, height: 792) // US paper portrait
        
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.frame = frameView.frame
        pdfView.collectionView.reloadData()
        frameView.addSubview(pdfView)
        pdfView.center = frameView.center
        let pdfPageFrame = frameView.bounds
        
        let pdfData = NSMutableData()
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageFrame, nil)
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
        guard let pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        frameView.layer.render(in: pdfContext)
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
        try pdfData.write(to: galleryExportedPDFURL, options: .atomic)
```

(And then I send the URL to the activity controller).